# strange dropdown behavior in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, knockout.js

I have this combobox HTML:

```
<select class="selects" name="projectTown" id="projectTown" 
  data-bind="options:availableTowns, value: projectTown, click: loadComboValues">
</select>
```

As you can see, when the dropbox is clicked I'm executing the `loadComboValues` function.

Here it is:

```
loadComboValues = function(){
          if(isForUpdate() == "yes"){
              availableTowns([]);
              availableTowns.push("1");
              availableTowns.push("2");
              availableTowns.push("3");
              availableTowns.push("4");
              availableTowns.push("5");
              availableTowns.push("6");
           }
};
```

What I'm doing is to re-populate the combo box values(I really have to do this *only* when the combobox is clicked). It seems to be working, but there is as strange behavior in google chrome.On the 1st click I can't see all the values, so I have to click again in order to load the full list of options. Here is an example:

After the 1st click:
[image]

And when I click it again(now with the full list)
[image]

What am I missing here? I know that it should be something really small and simple, but I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: Are you able to crop those images? They're making your question difficult to read.

Comment: @AdrianWragg cropped. :)

Comment: Much better, thanks. :)

Comment: I've seen this in Chrome when you try and change the options while the select is visible. Try blur/reopen the select after you change the options - trying to find a reference question as it's come up here before - [jQuery Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFG5t/1/)

Comment: @RGraham Great, but this is not running in firefox. :(

Comment: @Slim You might not have the same issue in Firefox so you may need to do some browser sniffing

Comment: @RGraham oks. Thanks for the help! I will try to customize for my needs. :)

Comment: I created a fiddle for your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueEddie/7hVAv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work as desired if you use a `focus` event binding instead of `click` (tested in Chrome on Windows):

```
<select class="selects" name="projectTown" id="projectTown" 
  data-bind="event: { focus: loadComboValues }, options:availableTowns, value: projectTown">
</select>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hVAv/5/

**Edit (thanks to Robert Slaney's comment):**

This only works if you can update the options synchronously (for instance: from another part of your application that's already been loaded into the browser). An ajax request initiated from here will most likely fail in the same way the click handler is failing, because it releases control back to the browser before the options are updated.

Comment: If you add a delay to the population of the observableArray ( ie simulate ajax call with a setTimeout ) you get the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, the reason it works is the browser is calling the focus callback before the options get drawn, but if you need to do something asynchronous to get the updated options then you may need to go with RGraham's blur/reopen method from the question comments.